# Calling WebApi Controller methods from other classes in the project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I am very new to WebApi (and really rusty in my C#.net).

So I have made a controller class and it is working fine when tested with a web browser.The Controller class receives data and put it in a database. Here is the definition of the method:

```
// POST: api/Books
    [ResponseType(typeof(Book))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostBook(Book book)
    {}
```

It also queries the database and returns a JSON object (as usual). It looks like this:

```
// GET: api/Books
    public IQueryable<BookDTO> GetBooks()
    {}
```

My question is whether it is a good practice to use these methods inside other classes of the same project. For instance, can a separate class call the GetBooks() method so it can proceed to do some classifications on them? Or can another controller call methods from this controller? Is it a good practice?

I hope my question is clear. Sorry for any confusion.

Thanks

Comment: refactor out the data-access in a *Repository* class (or however you like to call it) and use that - this code has no place in your controller anyway

Comment: Do you really need a Repository pattern when using Entity Framework? Also, the code came from Microsoft's site. So what are the chances its a bad implementation?

Comment: no you don't need a pattern but you should not mix everything up in the controller either - it's called separation of concerns and the controller should be really tiny code-wise - and to be honest: I don't care where the code comes from - bad habits are bad habits. See you yourself was trapped by it: it's really hard to reuse the code right? Now to test or use it you might have to prepare really ugly contexts and stuff ... **argh**

Comment: @CarstenKönig.. Thanks for the reply. I agree that bad habits are bad habits regardless of where it came from. Sorry about that.. What I am planning to go with is using EF followed by a service pattern.. and controllers on top. I am going to hold off using another layer of repo between service layer and EF till i find a real good reason for it..